Код, написанный на C++, не запускается в vs-коде, но файл компилируется. Когда я пытаюсь его открыть, просто сразу закрывается .exe
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
PS C:\Users\Данил\Desktop\P> g++ c.cpp
// компилируется в файл a.exe
PS C:\Users\Данил\Desktop\P> .\a  
// но не запускается даже через обычную консоль 
PS C:\Users\Данил\Desktop\P> 


А разве не .\a.exe ?

Не забывайте подкладывать к исполняемому файлу dll зависимости, рантайм от gcc.

Что-то не так с DLL. Попробуйте запустить дабл-кликом из проводника, он скажет каких не хватает. Или компилируйте с флагом -static, чтобы не зависеть от dll-ек (но лучше их просто подложить).

HolyBlackCat
когда запускаешь дабл-кликом запускается и сразу закрывается но если через -static то всё ок
скажи пожалуйста можно как то dll просто переставить
